# Symbolicate Crash report objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

[image]

This is the code snippet

```
 -(IBAction)btnPrintClicked:(id)sender
    {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setupPrinting) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }

-(void)setupPrinting
{

    AppAppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        if([arrSelPrinters count]>0){
    if([[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Bluetooth"])
    {
        [self BluetoothPrintingg:0];


    }
    else
    {

        for(int p=0;p<[arrSelPrinters count];p++)
        {

            [self starPrinting:p];
        }
    }
    }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Printer not selected" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                   [alert show];
                   [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                   return;
        }
-(void)starPrinting:(int *)pd
{    
    AppAppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    SelPrintertag = pd;
    NSString *strCustomerName=@"";
    NSString *strRestaurantName=@"";
    NSString *strcustomerph=@"";
    NSString *orderdeliverydate=@"";


    if ([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"EntityType"] isEqualToString:@"PickUp"])
    {
        NSArray *date1=[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Time"] componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];

        NSString *d1=[date1 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *date2=[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"DeliveryDate"]componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];

        NSString *d2=[date2 objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        NSDate *date11 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: d2];
        dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

        NSString *convertedString1 = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date11];
        orderdeliverydate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",convertedString1,d1];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *date1=[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Time"] componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];

        NSString *d1=[date1 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *date2=[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"DeliveryDate"]componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];

        NSString *d2=[date2 objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        NSDate *date11 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: d2];
        dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

        NSString *convertedString1 = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date11];
        orderdeliverydate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",convertedString1,d1];
    }

    if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"FirstName"]length]>0)
        strCustomerName=[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
    if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"LastName"]length]>0 && !([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"LastName"] rangeOfString:@"null"].location != NSNotFound))
        strCustomerName=[strCustomerName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"LastName"]]];
    strCustomerName=strCustomerName;


    strRestaurantName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"AppName"],[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"LocationName"]];



    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YY hh:mm a"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);

    NSString *strdelFee=@"";
    NSString *strttip=@"";


    if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"DeliveryFee"] length]>0)
    {
        float del=0;
        del=[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"DeliveryFee"]  floatValue];
        strdelFee=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%0.02f",self.CurrencySign,del];

    }
    else
    {
        strdelFee= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0.00",self.CurrencySign];

    }
    if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"OrderTip"] length]>0)
    {
        float tip=0;

        tip=[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"OrderTip"]  floatValue];
        strttip=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%0.02f",self.CurrencySign,tip];


    }


    else
    {
        strttip=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0.00",self.CurrencySign];

    }

    ModelIndex modelIndex = [ModelCapability modelIndexAtModelName:[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"ModelName"]];

    if (modelIndex == ModelIndexTSP100)
    {


        if( [[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"Receipt"] isEqualToString:@"true" ] )
        {
            _strprint=@"No";
            [self _starprintbody];

        }
        else if([[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"Kitchen"]isEqualToString:@"true" ]){
            _strprint=@"Yes";
            [self _starprintbody3];

        }

        else
        {
            _strprint=@"No";
            [self _starprintbody];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        [AppAppDelegate setSelectedPaperSize:PaperSizeIndexEscPosThreeInch];
        [AppAppDelegate setSelectedLanguage:0];     // Same!!!

        NSLog(@"%ld",[[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"EmulationValue"] integerValue]);
    long error_code = [[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"EmulationValue"] integerValue];

        ISCBBuilder *builder = [StarIoExt createCommandBuilder:
                                error_code];


        // ISCBBuilder *builder = [StarIoExt createCommandBuilder: [AppAppDelegate getEmulation]];

        [builder beginDocument];

        if( [[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"Receipt"] isEqualToString:@"true" ] )
        {
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"**************Receipt Print**************\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionCenter];

        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"                        \n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionCenter];

        NSData *strorderId = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OrderId: %@\n",[self.drrOrderDet objectForKey:@"GenerateId"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strorderId position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];

        NSData *strOrderType = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Type: %@\n",[self.drrOrderDet objectForKey:@"EntityType"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strOrderType position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
            NSData *AdvancedLabel = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@\n",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"AdvancedLabel"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                  [builder appendDataWithAlignment:AdvancedLabel position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        NSData *strRestaurant = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Restaurant: %@\n",strRestaurantName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strRestaurant position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        NSData *strDateTime = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Date & Time: %@\n",dateString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strDateTime position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];


        //  NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color };
        // NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"PrepareBy"] attributes:attrs];


        NSData *strprepareby = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"PrepareBy"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strprepareby position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];

        NSData *strCustomer = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Customer: %@\n",strCustomerName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strCustomer position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        if ([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"EntityType"] isEqualToString:@"PickUp"]) {

            NSData *strDeliveryDate = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PickUp Date & Time: %@\n",orderdeliverydate] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strDeliveryDate position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        }
        else
        {

            NSData *strDeliveryDate = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delivery Date & Time: %@\n",orderdeliverydate] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strDeliveryDate position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        }


        if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"PhoneNumber"] length]>0)
        {
            strcustomerph=[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"PhoneNumber"];

            NSData *strphono = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ph#:%@\n",strcustomerph] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strphono position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];

        }

            NSData *strOrderedFrom = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order From:%@\n",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Platforms"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strOrderedFrom position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
            NSString *strPayment=@"";
            if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"PaymentMode"]isEqualToString:@"Cash"])
            {
                strPayment=@"*Not Paid collect Payment*";
            }
            else
            {

                strPayment=@"Payment received do not charge";
            }
            NSData *strPaymentMode = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",strPayment] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strPaymentMode position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
            [builder appendUnderLine:YES];

        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"                                      \n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        [builder appendUnderLine:NO];

        for(int i=0;i<[Itemsarray count];i++)
        {

            NSMutableDictionary *d =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [[Itemsarray objectAtIndex:i] lastObject]];

            NSMutableArray *choicesarray;
            choicesarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[Itemsarray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0]];



            NSString *choicename=@"";
            strcheckforprint=nil;
            NSString *finalchoicecontent=@"";
            NSString *itemPrice=@"";


            for (int i=0;i<[choicesarray count];i++)
            {
                if([[[choicesarray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"OptionName"] length]>0)
                {
                    if(i==0)
                        choicename=[choicename stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",[[choicesarray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"OptionName"]]];
                    else
                        choicename=[choicename stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@:",[[choicesarray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"OptionName"]]];

                }
                if([[[choicesarray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ChoiceName"] length]>0)
                {
                    NSString *h=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" / %@",[[choicesarray  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ChoiceName"]];
                    choicename=[choicename stringByAppendingString:h];
                }

            }
            if([choicesarray count]>0)
            {

                NSString *newStr;


                newStr=[choicename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@": /" withString:@":"];

                finalchoicecontent=newStr;


            }


            itemPrice=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.CurrencySign,[d valueForKey:@"Price"]];


            NSString *s1;



            }

        }


        [builder appendUnderLine:YES];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"                                      \n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        [builder appendUnderLine:NO];
         NSData *strTipPrice = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",strttip] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strTipPrice position:SCBAlignmentPositionRight];

        NSData *strDeliFee = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DeliveryFee:                     "] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strDeliFee position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        NSData *strDeliFeePrice = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",strdelFee] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strDeliFeePrice position:SCBAlignmentPositionRight];
           NSString *strmainTotal= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.CurrencySign,[formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"TotalPrice"]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" ]floatValue]]]];

        NSData *strTotal = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total:                           "] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strTotal position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
        NSData *strTotalPrice = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",strmainTotal] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strTotalPrice position:SCBAlignmentPositionRight];
           if (![[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"EntityType"] isEqualToString:@"PickUp"]) {
          NSString  *strDeiveryAddress=@"Delivery Address:\n";
            if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Line1"]length]>0)
            {
                NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Line1"]];
                strDeiveryAddress=[strDeiveryAddress stringByAppendingString:str];

            }


            [builder appendUnderLine:YES];
            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"                                      \n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];
            [builder appendUnderLine:NO];


            if([[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Note"]length]>0)
            {

                UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor]; // select needed color
                //  NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color };
                //    NSAttributedString *attrStr1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Instructions: %@\n",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Note"]] attributes:attrs];

                NSData *strInstruction = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Instructions: %@\n",[self.OrderDetailsbygenId objectForKey:@"Note"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strInstruction position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];

            }

            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionCenter];
            NSData *strorderId = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OrderId: %@\n",[self.drrOrderDet objectForKey:@"GenerateId"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:strorderId position:SCBAlignmentPositionLeft];

              [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionCenter];

            [builder appendDataWithAlignment:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"******************************************\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] position:SCBAlignmentPositionCenter];
        }


        [builder appendCutPaper:SCBCutPaperActionPartialCutWithFeed];

        [builder endDocument];


        NSData *commands = nil;

        commands = [builder.commands copy];


        NSString *portName     = [[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"PortName"];
        NSString *portSettings = [[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"PortSettings"];
        [Communication sendCommands:commands
                           portName:portName
                       portSettings:portSettings
                            timeout:10000
                  completionHandler:^(BOOL result, NSString *title, NSString *message) {
//                       dispatch_async(GlobalQueueManager.sharedManager.serialQueue, ^{

//                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      if ([message isEqualToString:@"Success"])
                      {
//

                          [alertPrinting dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                          if (strAlertdismiss) {
                              strAlertdismiss=false;
                          NSString*strmsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully printed Order %@",[self.drrOrderDet objectForKey:@"GenerateId"]];

                              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:strmsg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                           [alertView show];
                          }
                          [activityIndicator stopAnimating];



                      }
                      else
                      {
                          [alertPrinting dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                          if (strSP700Fail) {
                              strSP700Fail=false;

                          UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Printing failed"
                                                                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Please check %@ printer's connection and ensure that it has enough paper.",[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"ModelName"]]
                                                                             delegate:nil
                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

                          [alertView show];
                          }
                          if (strmCPFail) {
                              strmCPFail=false;

                              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Printing failed"
                                                                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Please check %@ printer's connection and ensure that it has enough paper.",[[arrSelPrinters objectAtIndex:SelPrintertag]objectForKey:@"ModelName"]]
                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

                              [alertView show];
                          }
                          [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

                      }
                      [arrSelPrinters removeObjectAtIndex:SelPrintertag];

                      if(arrSelPrinters.count>0)
                          [self setupPrinting];

                  }];

    }
```

Can anybody plz suggest what does the error say doesNotRecogniseSelector and how to resolve it .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UserOrders class does not have setupPrinting method. Please add code snippet where this method is called and method declaration.

About this error message:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418637-doesnotrecognizeselector

Comment: setupPrinting method looks ok. May be something inside it. Please add declaration for BluetoothPrintingg, starPrinting methods. And is it really named 'BluetoothPrintingG'?

Comment: Also does arrSelPrinters contain only NSDictionary objects?

Comment: Plz chk now, I added starprinting method

Comment: At least int p is passed to starPrinting with int* argument. This is wrong. Also how SelPrintertag is declared?

Comment: I couldnt get what u said - "At least int p is passed to starPrinting with int* argument. This is wrong" Can u let me know plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213404/discussion-between-honey-and-denis).